# Get Test instance id using Java API

Tags: java, qtp, hp-alm

I want to query QC to get the test instance id under a test set using Java API. Could anybody tell me what URL to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the ALM REST API reference guide here:

http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/manuals

http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM997956/binary/ALM11.00_REST_API.html?searchIdentifier=-765a98c0%3a12de84ca170%3a-27ac&resultType=document

These both require logins so I can't provide any other information that the links really.

The main entry point it the authentication after then you can login to project, create entities and more using the exposed resources.

[source](http://community.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-Practitioners/How-to-access-ALM-data-using-REST-API/td-p/4775940)